# Select row from a MAX() GROUP BY in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have a table I called `Eventos`. I have to select the corresponding `outTime` from the alarm which has the greater `inTime`.

And I have to do it quickly/optimized. I have about 1 million entries in the table.

This is my code:

```
SELECT 
    CadGrupoEventos.Severidade AS Nível, 
    CadGrupoEquipamentos.Nome AS Grupo, 
    CadEquipamentos.TAG AS Equipamento, 
    CadEventos.MensagemPT AS 'Mensagem de alarme', 
    MAX(Eventos.InTime) AS 'Hora do evento', 
    Eventos.OutTime AS 'Hora de saída'
FROM 
    CadGrupoEventos, 
    CadEquipamentos, 
    CadEventos, 
    Eventos, 
    CadUsuarios, 
    CadGrupoEquipamentos
WHERE 
    Eventos.Acked = 0 
    AND CadGrupoEventos.Codigo = CadEventos.Grupo 
    AND CadEquipamentos.Codigo = Eventos.TAG 
    AND CadEventos.Codigo = Eventos.CodMensagem 
    AND CadGrupoEquipamentos.Codigo = CadEquipamentos.Grupo
GROUP BY 
    CadGrupoEventos.Severidade, 
    CadEquipamentos.TAG, 
    CadEventos.MensagemPT, 
    CadGrupoEquipamentos.Nome, 
    Eventos.OutTime
```

This code, as it is, returns every single entry from the table.

I have to take `Eventos.OutTime` out of `GROUP BY` and still get the value of it.

Comment: Word of advice ... stop using the old style join, it is very hard to read and follow. Please use the new standard From Table Inner JOin Table2 on table1.col = table2.col left join table 3 on ..etc...https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/10/08/sql-server-why-should-you-not-to-use-old-style-join/

Comment: Could you add some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an educated guess based on your description. Notice I used ANSI-92 style joins which are much more explicit. I also used aliases to make this a lot more legible. Your query might look something like this.

```
select x.Severidade AS Nível, 
       x.Nome AS Grupo, 
       x.TAG AS Equipamento, 
       x.MensagemPT AS [Mensagem de alarme], 
       x.[Hora do evento], 
       x.OutTime AS [Hora de saída]
from
(
    SELECT cge.Severidade, 
           cgequip.Nome, 
           ce.TAG, 
           cevt.MensagemPT, 
           MAX(e.InTime) AS [Hora do evento], 
           e.OutTime
           , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by cge.Severidade, ce.TAG, cevt.MensagemPT, cgequip.Nome order by e.OutTime /*maybe desc???*/)
    FROM CadGrupoEventos cge 
    join CadEventos cevt on cge.Codigo = cevt.Grupo     
    join Eventos e on AND cevt.Codigo = e.CodMensagem 
    join CadEquipamentos ce on ce.Codigo = e.TAG 
    join CadGrupoEquipamentos cgequip on cgequip.Codigo = ce.Grupo
    cross join CadUsuarios cu --not sure if this is really what you want but your original code did not have any logic for this table
    WHERE e.Acked = 0 
    GROUP BY cge.Severidade, 
             ce.TAG, 
             cevt.MensagemPT, 
             cgequip.Nome, 
             e.OutTime
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```